# How to find file corresponding to ld (linker) flag?

Tags: ld

so the short version first: If I link some programs via ld with `ld -someflag ..` how can I find out which library `-someflag` belongs to?

Long Version:
I need to compile a rather complex FOTRAN library. On machine1 the compilation works without errors (Fedora). On my second machine, machine2 (Debian) I get the following two linker errors:

```
ld: cannot find -lmkl_intel
ld: cannot find -lguide
```

Since I couldn't find any information on where those two files belong to, I thought about using machine1, but I got no idea how to find that out.
From my perspective I installed the exact same libraries on machine1 and machine2, but apperently something is missing or different in those two operating systems.
Thanks for your help

I already tried to search through all libraries contanined in the lb path on machine 1, but that didn't return any matching the names `lmk_intel` or `guide`

Comment: Try to read the description of the `-l` option in `man ld`.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. The libraries will be libmk_intel (or libmkl_intel, it looks like a typo) and libguide (or another typo, libguile?) with the .so or .a extension. But it is hard to say where to look for them. You or the system admin must know whether and where you installed those libraries to that computer.

Comment: I understood the `-l` option but on machine 1 I can't find the libraries mentioned in my ld search path. Anyway the linker runs without an error. And I edited mk to mkl